# find the collections, the circular regions over which intersects a particular geo point in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

I have a collection of responders, having documents with geolocation coordinates(latitude and longitude) and the radius of which they can serve, want to find whether one geolocation point(customer location) intersects in the circular region having center as the geolocation coordinates from document and radius having the radius from the document.

Responder Collection :

```
{
    "location": {
      "lat": 19.0335097,
      "lng": 73.01813479999998
    },
    "locationName": "A",
    "radius": "100"
},
{
    "location": {
      "lat": 19.046777,
      "lng": 73.06978099999992
    },
    "locationName": "B",
    "radius": "100"
},
{
    "location": {
      "lat": 18.9985832,
      "lng": 72.85472909999999
    },
    "locationName": "C",
    "radius": "100"
}
```

I want to find which among the documents intersects the point having geolocation {"lat": 18.99,"lng": 72.85}

Comment: `"radius"` is a "string". So it cannot be used in that form as it would need to be numeric for any comparison. Also you really should update to GeoJSON format when fixing those strings. Then be mindful of "what" measurement radius actually is, because GeoJSON uses "meters" as a standard, yet if you don't store GeoJSON then MongoDB returns "radians" as the units instead. So you want to make things numeric and then convert the points to GeoJSON first.

Answer (score 0):

So given a candidate point `{"lat": 18.99,"lng": 72.85}` you want to find which circles encompass that point, where each doc defines the circle as a center and a radius.  OK, first what Neil said, change `radius` to a numeric not a string.  And if you can you should morph the data to GeoJSON standard.
Next, what you have to do is compute the distance from the circle center to the candidate and check that against the radius.  If the distance <= radius, then the circle (and the document) matches.   This is a "sample" solution.  NOTE: The distance computation assumes relatively short distances because it does NOT take 3D spherical coord geometry into account:

```
db.foo.aggregate([

// Stage 1: Compute distance from candidate: Pythagorean theorem:
,{$addFields: {dist: {$sqrt: {$add: [
{$pow:[ {$subtract: [ {$arrayElemAt:[ "$loc.coordinates",0]}, lng]} , 2]}
,{$pow:[ {$subtract:[ {$arrayElemAt:[ "$loc.coordinates", 1]}, lat]} , 2]}
                         ]}
        }}}

// Stage 2: If the distance <= $radius, then inside = 1 else 0:
,{$addFields: {"inside": {$cond: [
     {$lte: [ "$dist", "$radius" ]}, 1, 0] }}}

// Now just pick where inside = 1:
,{$match: {"inside": 1}}
                    ]);
```